# When is every prime element of a Noetherian UFD irreducible in a simple algebraic ring extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, noetherian, unique-factorization-domains

Let $D$ be a Noetherian UFD over a field $k$ of characteristic zero.

Let $w$ be an algebraic, non-integral element over $D$,
and denote its minimal polynomial over $D$ by 
$h(T)=d_nT^n+\cdots+d_1T+d_0$, $d_j \in D$.

Denote $R=D[w]$; it is a Noetherian integral domain, but it is not necessarily a UFD.

> When is every prime element of $D$ irreducible in $R$? (By 'when' I mean what should be the $d_j$'s, or additional assumptions on $D$).

**Remarks:** 
(1) $D$ is a UFD, so primes=irreducibles.

(2) $R$ is not necessarily a UFD, so it may not have prime elements,
but it is Noetherian so every element of $R$ is a product (not necessarily unique) of irreducible elements of $R$.

(3) If $d \in D$ is prime/irreducible, it may happen that $d$ is reducible in $R$; for example: If $d_0$ is prime, then 
$d_0=-(d_nw^{n-1}+\cdots+d_1)w$ is reducible.

(4) Please notice that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1995100/when-irreducib) is almost identical to the current question; however, its answer actually answers a previous version of that question, so that question is unanswered.
Please also see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2002699/when-an-irreducible-d-in-d-remains-irreducible-in-dt-p?noredirect=1&lq=1) unanswered question.

Thank you very much for any hints and comments!

Comment: Is every prime element of $D$ also prime in $R$?

Comment: This is not known; if I knew that it was a prime element of $R$, then it immediately follows that it is irreducible in $R$.