# When a simple algebraic ring extension of a UFD is a UFD

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, unique-factorization-domains

Let $k$ be a field and let $R$ be a UFD, which is a $k$-algebra. Let $w$ be an algebraic element over $R$, namely, there exists a polynomial $f(T) \in  R[T]$ such that $f(w)=0$. Denote $S=R[w]$.

**Examples:**

**(1)** $R=k[x^2]$, $w=x^3$, $f(T)=T^2-x^2x^2x^2$, $S=k[x^2,x^3]$.

**(2)** $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $w=\frac{1}{2}$, $f(T)=2T-1$, $S=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$.

**(3)** $R=\mathbb{Q}$, $w=\sqrt{2}$, $f(T)=T^2-2$, $S=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$.

**(4)** $R=\mathbb{R}$, $w=i$, $f(T)=T^2+1$, $S=\mathbb{R}[i]=\mathbb{C}$.

If I am not wrong, $S$ is a UFD + $w$ is prime or invertible in $S$, in examples
**(2)**,**(3)**,**(4)**.
In contrast, $S$ is not a UFD and $w$ is not a prime ($x^3$ divides $x^2x^2x^2$, but $x^3$ does not divide $x^2$) nor invertible in example **(1)**.

> **My claim:** If $w$ is a prime element of $S$ (or an invertible element of $S$), then $S$ is also a UFD.

> **Question:** Is my claim true? At least if $w$ is a prime element of $S$.
> I do not mind to further assume that $k=\mathbb{C}$.
> Indeed, according to the first comment in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276356/a-simple-algebraic-ring-extension-of-a-ufd-having-no-prime-elements) question, $x^2+1$ is prime in $S=\mathbb{R}[x^3][x^2+1]=\mathbb{R}[x^3][x^2]$,
> but $S$ is not a UFD, so we should assume that $k=\mathbb{C}$.

**Remark:** $w \in S$ is a prime element in $S$ iff $(w)$ is a prime ideal in $S$ iff $S/(w)$ is an integral domain.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to generalize the $k=\mathbb{R}$ counterexample you cite to the $k=\mathbb{C}$ case.

Let $R=\mathbb{C}(t)[x^3]$ and let $w=x^2-t$.  Then $S=R[w]$ is not a UFD; for $S\cong\mathbb{C}(t)[x^3,x^2]$, which supports two factorizations of $x^6$.

But $w$ is prime in $S$, as \begin{align*}
S/(w)&=\mathbb{C}(t)[x^3,x^2]/(x^2-t) \\
&=\mathbb{C}(t)[tx,t]/(x^2-t) \\
&=\mathbb{C}(t)[x]/(x^2-t) \\
&\cong\mathbb{C}(t)[\sqrt{t}] \\
&\cong\mathbb{C}(\sqrt{t})
\end{align*} is an integral domain.

<s>For a finite-dimensional (over $k$) counterexample, one can take $R/(x^9)$, and proceed as above.</s>  Never mind, that's finite-dimensional over $\mathbb{C}(t)$, but not $\mathbb{C}$.   In fact, there are no finite-dimensional counterexamples, since then $R$ would be Artinian and (since a domain) a field.  But $\mathbb{C}$ has no nontrivial finite-degree field extensions.

Comment: Thank you very much! Nice. Please, could you explain why $S/(w) \cong \mathbb{C}(t)[\sqrt{t}]$?

Comment: Please, I wonder, what if we assume that: (1) $k=\mathbb{C}$. (2) The invertible elements in $R$ and in $S$ are $k-\{0\}$ only?

Comment: I've added more detail to the computation of $S/(w)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for adding the details.

Comment: As to your second comment: the above works with $\mathbb{C}[t]$, rather than $\mathbb{C}(t)$; it's just that then writing down $S/(w)$ is a little trickier.  So requiring the units of $R$ to be $k^{\times}$ doesn't save us.

Comment: Thank you again. Interesting.